# How to achieve following result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a code like this:

```
var exist_file = document.getElementById('exist_file').value;
        document.getElementById('dialog-confirm-upload').innerHTML=

             "The file" + 
             for (var i=0;i<exist_file.length;i++){
                 exist_file + ","
             }

             +
             "has been already transferred? Do you want to overwrite?"
```

exist_file is an array which contains one or more than one element: ['hello', 'ok']. I want to pass the value to `innerHTML` like this.
 `"The file hello, ok has been already transferred? Do you want to overwrite?"` I tried the following above code but it turns out that's not a valid syntax. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like `exist_file` is a string rather than an array.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because you say that exist_file is an array like `['hello', 'ok']`, but in your sample code, you're actually getting it as the value of an input element. Which is it? where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to parse the string into an array, then you can format it with commas:

```
var exist_file = document.getElementById('exist_file').value;
document.getElementById('dialog-confirm-upload').innerHTML=
  "The file " + 
  exist_file.substr(3, exist_file.length - 5).split("', u'").join(", ") +
  " has already been transferred. Do you want to overwrite?"
```

Note: This is the most basic form of parsing. It works with strings containing regular characters, but escaped characters are not unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exist_file = document.getElementById('exist_file').value,
     msg = "The file" + exist_file.toString() + "has been already transferred? Do you want to overwrite?";
    document.getElementById('dialog-confirm-upload').innerHTML= msg;
```

This snippet works for both cases where `exist_file` is an array or a string.

Comment: It does. Since it's the array from python, it is string to the javascript. Your code works fine but instead of showing this [u'init.py']  I want to show just init.py to the user. Also if there are more than one file I want comma like this: __init__.py, hello